# Choosing load balancing strategy in JDBC connection string

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, load-balancing

Currently my connection string looks like below

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://server1:3306,server2:3306/sample_db?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

Where server1, server2 are ips of `MASTER-MASTER` replicated MySQL servers.

As far as I know, loadbalancing will be done by default "roundrobin" strategy.

## The question is

Is there any strategy that checks health of server before connection?
How to change strategy and what strategies are available?

I googled a lot, only thing I've found is:

> ```
> jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://host-1,host-2,...host-n/database?loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000
> ```
>
> The "loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout" adds the needed feature that failed
> connections in a connection pool are put aside for the specified time,
> and only working connections are utilized.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 common load balancing strategies. One of them random (roundrobin) which comes by default. Second is `best response time` which looks like below:

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://ip1:3306,ip2:3306/messenger?rewriteBatchedStatements=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=10000&loadBalanceStrategy=bestResponseTime
```